# highlight with code instead of text

Tags: django, templates, filter, highlight, django-haystack

I have problem with highlight in django app template. Below is my code and I get text and part of jQuery code.
I tried with `safe` filter but it is not working for me.

```
{% highlight other.raw_content with search_query html_tag "b" max_length 300 %}
```

Comment: What haystack version?

Comment: With any search query?

Comment: What's in `raw_content`?

Comment: @andrey-shipilov Haystack version: `django-haystack==2.4.1` 
`raw_content = indexes.CharField(model_attr='get_raw_content')`

Comment: Hm. Not sure here then. As I said, works fine on my end. I'd suggest trying updating to the latest one cause frankly 2.4.1 is more than one year old release.

Comment: @andrey-shipilov I removed `django-haystack==2.4.1` and installed `django-haystack==2.6.0` but I got 500 error.
`[17/Jan/2017 12:26:15] "GET /de/suche?q=Er%C3%B6ffnungs HTTP/1.1" 500 26725`